# How to handle redirects that do not use 3XX status codes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, http-status-codes

By default, `allow_redirects` is typically true, but that does not seem to handle redirects that give out non-3XX status codes.

More specifically, how do I handle

```
>>> r = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass')) 
# example url
>>> r.status_code
200
>>> r.text
<p>Redirecting...</p>
```

And going to the site manually does reveal that the page indeed redirects despite giving a `200`.

edit:
My current solution for now. Might clean it up later

```
def meta_redirect(html_text, uri):
    start = html_text.find('<metahttp-equiv="refresh"content="0;url=') + 40
    end = html_text.find('"', start)
    redirect = html_text[start:end]
    if "http" in redirect:
        return redirect
    return '/'.join([uri, redirect])

def main():
    uri = 'https://api.github.com/user'
    r = requests.get(uri, auth=('user', 'pass')) 
    html_text = r.text.lower().replace("'", '"').replace(" ", "")
    while '<metahttp-equiv="refresh"content="0;url=' in html_text:
        r = requests.get(meta_redirect(html_text, uri), auth=('user', 'pass'))
        html_text = r.text.lower().replace("'", '"').replace(" ", "")
    return r
```

Comment: A number of sites like this have the redirect in either the HTML or the Javascript. Often in the header (e.g. `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='http://new-website.com'" />`). Try parsing the response body and seeing if you can find the link it's supposed to be sending you to.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy I managed to find it, though it is a path instead of a header. How do I deal with that?

Comment: sorry, *in* the header, by which I meant the `<head></head>` part of the HTML document. If you can find it, then see if you can code something up to parse what you get and extract that link, then send a request to it. Individual websites tend to be consistent in how they do redirects, although you might have to build a different parser for different websites.